# "This is borderline with comments" versus "this is borderline with being a comment"

Tags: phrase-choice

Supposing that I am commenting about an answer given from somebody on Stack Exchange that is so short that could be a comment, what should I say?

> This [the answer for which I am leaving the comment] is borderline with being a comment.
>   This is borderline with comments.

Comment: Don't use *borderline* in the first place. Just say *"[This borders on being](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22this+borders+on+being%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) a comment"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say something like:

> This is almost just a comment.  Next time, please consider just adding a comment if your answer is this short.

If you really want to use the word "borderline", you might say something like this:

> This answer borders on being just a comment.  If your answer is on the borderline like this one, please consider making it a comment instead of an answer.

**Edit:**
You could also say something like this:

> In the case of a borderline comment like this short answer, next time please consider just making it a comment.

Comment: If I were to use _borderline_ as adjective, which sentence should I use? (I mean, if that makes any sense or it is possible in the case I am describing.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I added a third usage that more closely matches your request of an adjective.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was perfect as it was before, and it now helps me understanding how I should use _borderline_. I take you would rather avoiding using _borderline_, and that is useful information too.